# Conditionally setting properties in jQuery.css()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have like 40 `foo`'s on the page, and each one is assigned a left/top value in another function.

```
$('.foo').css({
  top: isOn ? current_top_value_here : 500,
  left: isOn ? current_left_value_here : 500
});
```

so, I want to leave the top & left properties unmodified if `isOn` is true. How can I do that?

Comment: what is `isOn`?  Javascript variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way you can ensure they are only added if it's needed. Set up the object first with those values that you want assigned, and conditionally add some more. Then you can pass the object to your `.css()`.

```
var cssProperties={
    'color' : 'yellow',
    ...
};

if (isOn) {
    cssProperties.top=500;
    cssProperties.left=500;
    /* alternative: $.extend(cssProperties, { 'top': 500, 'left': 500 }); */
}

$('.foo').css(cssProperties);
```

Comment: In case I have misunderstood something, please show more of your code and explain what you need in a bit more detail. There might be good alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would probably just be to not call it at all.  If you have other css you're setting in the same statement, just split it apart:

```
if(!isOn){
  $('.foo').css({
    top: 500,
    left: 500
  });
}

$('.foo').css({
   // other stuff
});
```

Comment: but that means I have to duplicate my code, add like 20 lines+. I also have a animate function where I need to conditionally animate these properties too...

Comment: At least save the jQuery collection first, running `$('.foo')` twice is not a good practice.

Comment: @baz Yup, was just illustrating the idea, not optimizing it.  Your idea is better anyway though, now that the question is further explained.

Comment: Meant no offense, just wanted to mention it in case somebody visits this question later for a code example to use :).